# Worksheet Change Event Non Contiguous Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write for a worksheet change event for two non contiguous range , which are cells A&lastrow and C&lastrow. For example, if lastrow=5, then it is A5, and C5, while excluding B5. This is my code, and it is not working, any idea on how to fix the syntax.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = 5

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A & lastrow, C & lastrow ")) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Hello"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA's & string concatenation operator isn't part of the string literal; neither is the lastrow local variable, so you want `Me.Range("A" & lastrow & ", C" & lastrow & ")")` here.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, tried it and it's not working.

Comment: `if target = cells(lastrow, 1) or target = cells(lastrow, 3) then msgbox "Hello"` ?

Comment: Hi I understand using that maethod, but I am trying to solve it using non intersect method , guess it doesnt work

Comment: Don't quite understand why you need the intersection while you can just directly check if the target cell meet the criteria. Anyway, if using intersect then maybe use union ? `if not intersect(target,union(range("A" & lastrow),range("D"&lastrow))) is nothing then msgbox "hello"`

Comment: Or `Me.Rows(lastrow).Range("A1,C1")`

Comment: @Karma, Your answer works!! Great job!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Mathieu Guindons code snippet there are too many quotation marks.

This works code shows the msgbox when cell A5 or C5 are changed

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = 5

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A" & lastrow & ", C" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "hello"
End If

End Sub
```